# Clear The Data In A Network Stream Without Disposing It

Tags: .net, vb.net, networkstream

How can you clear the data in a network stream without disposing it?

```
Dim ns As NetworkStream
```

**Edit:**

Based on the comment below by **James**, it seems that this question is not yet answered properly.

I thought doing:

```
ns = Nothing
```

would clear the network stream, but I was wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing the variable 'ns' with the network stream it references.

Comment: FYI - setting the stream to `nothing` will cause a GC at some point which essentially *will* dispose it.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the information @James. Does that mean that when it gets disposed, the resources in it will also get disposed including the socket? Is it like calling the NetworkStream.Close()? If that's the case, then how do you clear the network stream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume by "clear the network stream," you mean you want to empty the input buffer?

```
var buffer = new byte[4096];
while (ns.DataAvailable)
{
    ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

That throws away all the data, but leaves the stream open for reading.

If you mean that you want to clear the output buffer (on a writeable stream), I have no idea. You'll probably have to close the stream and create a new one.